# How to check if dask dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Is there a dask equivalent of pandas `empty` function? I want to check if a dask dataframe is empty but `df.empty` return `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'empty'`

Comment: I don't think so, but you can query `len(df) == 0`?

Comment: that does seem to work, thanks!

Comment: Adding the `empty` method would be an easy addition to the project if anyone wants to contribute a pull request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dask doesn't currently support this, but you can compute the length on the fly:

```
len(df) == 0
```

---

```
len(df.index) == 0 # Likely to be faster
```

Comment: Probably `len(df.index)==0` should be faster

Comment: @JosephBerry this is true with pandas, so I'm guessing you're right. Will test in a bit.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this operation? O(1)? Distributed O(1)? Or O(n) or distributed O(n)?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not familiar with dask's internals. I don't think the length is stored, so it has to be pre-computed at least the first time you call `len`. I would assume that is linear, although admittedly I don't understand the difference between O(n) and distributed O(n).

Comment: Because Dask dataframes are distributed across partitions across dask workers. I thought be distributed O(n). But I reckon the index might be precomputed ahead of time and shared across all partitions. Maybe is actually O(1). Hopefully somebody from Dask can clarify.

Comment: This doesn't work all the time. Check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511235/how-to-check-if-dask-dataframe-is-empty-and-lazily-evaluated

Comment: This is like a very in-efficent solition for checking if just **one** element is inside the dataframe.. Could point to counting millions or billions of row if you only want to find one.

Comment: I can just say, that `len(df.head().index)` and  `len(df.sample(frac=0.01).index)` is equally fast to `len(df.index)`, sadly..