# How to check if dask dataframe is empty if lazily evaluated?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206730/how-to-check-if-dask-dataframe-is-empty). But check the code(minimal-working example) below:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

categoric_df = dask_df.select_dtypes(include="category")
```

When I try to print the `categoric_df` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

And when I check the `categoric_df` from PyCharm debugger:

```
Unable to get repr for <class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
```

With these errors, I can build a try/except block to check if the dataframe is empty or not. But I don't want to use this approach since it is not guaranteed to work all the time and try/except slows down the code.
And when I try to print computed `categoric_df` it looks like this:

```
>>>print(categoric_df.compute())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

In summary: Here if I select the non-existing dypes and create a dask.DataFrame from it, I get a `dask.DataFrame` which at first glance doesn't seem empty if I use `len()` function.

```
>>>print(len(categoric_df))
4
>>>print(len(categoric_df.compute())
4
>>>print(categoric_df.compute().empty)
True
```

Is there a way to check if the `categoric_df` is empty or not without computing it? (I want it to stay lazily evaluated.)

> **UPDATE**: `print(len(categoric_df.columns))` is returning `0`. This can be used for figuring out if the dataframe is empty or not. But is
>   this viable? I am not sure.

Comment: I've just figured out that I can use `print(len(categoric_df.columns))` which prints out `0` if the dataframe is empty. But is this viable? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're run into a bug where a dataframe isn't printing correctly.  If you felt like raising a bug report at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new that would be the right place to report this.

This shouldn't affect the check that you want to do though. Looking at `.columns` to see if there are any columns seems reasonable.  The fact that the dataframe still has rows just means that there is still an index.

Comment: I just opened an issue as you suggested. I am waiting for a response...

Comment: @MehmedB if dask_df contains headers but no rows, len(dask_df.columns) won't return 0 and is not able to check empty.

Comment: @MehmedB Could you provide a link to the issue for reference, please?

Comment: @gies0r Here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5761