# blosc.MAX_BUFFERSIZE error while trying to guess if a dask dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dask, ray, blosc

I want to perform a test on the emptiness of a dask dataframe.
So I have this dask dataframe `ddf`, a local ray cluster, and dask configured to use ray as backend.

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50207206/4301236) that there is no `empty` property and that I have to perform the following code

```py
len(ddf.index) == 0
```

This results in `ValueError: bytesobj cannot be larger than 2147483631 bytes`, triggered by the following code (located in `blosc.toplevel`)

```py
def _check_input_length(input_name, input_len):
    if input_len > blosc.MAX_BUFFERSIZE:
        raise ValueError("%s cannot be larger than %d bytes" %
                         (input_name, blosc.MAX_BUFFERSIZE))
```

I have tried to get just one element out of the index, which will obviously answer the question that it's not empty, but this causes the same error to be triggered.

```py
a = ddf.index.tail(1)
b = ddf.index.head(1)
```

- Why I am having this error?
- How I could achieve my initial goal?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the number of partitions on the dask dataframe was 1.

I've used `ddf.repartition(npartitions=32)` to solve my issue.

`partition_size="100MB"` is the recommended way to go.